# preg_replace PHP

Tags: php, regex

I know this is really easy, and I've done it a million times myself; but it's late in the day and I have a brain meltdown.

I'm trying to match and replace whole words rather than every occurance.

So, I want to replace each occurance of the word 'me' and replace it with 'xxx'

Ie. 'Me meets smeg' becomes 'xxx meets smeg'

What I DO NOT want is:

'Me meets smeg' becomes 'xxx xxxets sxxg'

I know it's preg_match but I just can't remember the pattern matching for whole words.

Please help

Oliver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/\bme\b/i', 'xxx', $subject);
```

`\b` is the **word boundry** as defined in the [**PCRE Reference**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.backslash.php).

Answer (score 4):

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/\bme\b/i','xxx',$phrase);
```

Answer (score 2):

Word boundary characters

```
$output = preg_replace( "/\\bme\\b/", 'xxx', $input );
```

Answer (score 1):

[\b matches a word boundary](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.backslash.php), so something like `/\bMe\b/` (or `/\bme\b/i` for case insensitivity) should give you the regex you desire!

Answer (score 1):

You use the `\b` word boundary.

```
$str = preg_replace('/\bMe\b/', 'xx', $str);
```

For case insensitivity, use the `i` modifier:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\bme\b/i', 'xx', $str);
```